# CSS @media query is not working for some of tags

Tags: css, media-queries

I have written the following code to change the fonts to `5px`, while getting zoom - by 33%.

For `<a>` tag it works but for the rest of the elements it didn't.

Any suggestions, what can cause the reason?

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 5000px) {
      tbody:nth-of-type(1) th, 
      tbody:nth-of-type(1) td {
          font-size: 5px;
      }
      tbody:nth-of-type(2) th, 
      tbody:nth-of-type(2) td {
          font-size: 5px;
      }
      tbody:nth-of-type(1) a, 
      a:hover {
          font-size: 5px;
      }
      tbody:nth-of-type(1) tr::before {
          font-size: 5px;
      }
  }
```

Comment: for tag <a> I meant... code works just fine

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting your elements properly? Please provide some markup to which the CSS is applied.

Comment: 5000px is really large for a screen. I mean really really large. Are you sure that's what you meant? Also, `font-size:5px` may not work in browsers that have the minimum font size set to something bigger.

Comment: 5000px becomes the screen when the zoom is applied to 33% only, this is the actual size of body itself <body>. Here is the code part that applies in general, and that should be changed to 5px font size while zoom is applied to 33%.

Comment: tbody:nth-of-type(1) th {
         font-size: 18px;
    }

Comment: so the matter is that 18px remain as they are with no change, but the same for <a> works fine. strange isn't it?

Comment: Ah, when zooming. OK then. In that case, I can't reproduce the issue with the code provided here. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/noLrurpy/). So the issue must be with code not provided here!

Comment: thx, will check that up.